# Arrange Cell structure in matlab

Tags: matlab

I 'm reading dxf file in matlab and getting this structure. How can I safe all coordinates in separeted matrix having name same as layer name. I mean

> Plane1=[
>   10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5;...]
>
> **DATA**
>
> Line={[10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,0,10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane1';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane4';[10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5,10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5],'Plane4';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane4';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane3';[10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5,10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325],'Plane3';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000,8.19164033348243,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000],'Plane1';[8.19164033348243,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000,8.19164033348243,2.06417715317460,1.14583181629325],'Plane1';[8.19164033348243,2.06417715317460,1.14583181629325,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,1.14583181629325],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000],'Plane1';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane3';[8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000],'Plane3';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5],'Plane3';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane3';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325,8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325],'Plane3';[8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325,8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000],'Plane3';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000],'Plane3';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0],'Plan2';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5,10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5],'Plan2';[10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,0,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0],'Plan2';[10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,5,10.8031269501964,2.06417715317460,0],'Plan2';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,0,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,5,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,5,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,2.50000000000000,3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,0],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,0,3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,2.06417715317460,2.50000000000000,3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,5],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,5,3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,1.82291590814662],'Plane4';[3.70163846035642,7.75770563520633,1.82291590814662,3.70163846035642,4.91094139419046,0],'Plane4';[10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,5,8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000],'Plane3';[8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,2.50000000000000,8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325],'Plane3';[8.19164033348243,7.75770563520633,1.14583181629325,10.8031269501964,7.75770563520633,0],'Plane3';}

Comment: Shouldn't `Plan2` be `Plane2`? By layer name do you mean `Plane1` `Plane2`, etc.?

Comment: what do you mean with "this structure"? please be more specific. How did you read the file?

Comment: yes , its typing  mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using `eval` to use variables as names (which can lead to other problems) you could consider unpacking into a structure, which can be automated...

```
VectorLength=6; % length of the vectors in the input
names=unique(Line(:,2));

for ii=1:length(names);
 nameLocations=strcmp(Line(:,2),names{ii});
LineStruct.(names{ii})=...
    reshape([Line{nameLocations,1}],sum(nameLocations),VectorLength);
end
```

which gives

```
LineStruct = 

     Plan2: [4x6 double]
    Plane1: [9x6 double]
    Plane3: [12x6 double]
    Plane4: [15x6 double]
```

and the matrices can be used by calling the field of the structure eg `LineStruct.Plane1`

Comment: Though it's not really a new concept given the existing replies, it's still good to see things worked out in detail.

Comment: Had your post and comments been there when I started writing this I wouldnt have posted... as the approach is pritty much covered there, and the code (that would be) inside the loop is much nicer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it one plane at a time. It can of course be automated, but if you have a lot of planes you probably won't want to do this anyway:

```
Plane1 = Line(strcmp(Line(:,2),'Plane1'),1);
Plane1 = vertcat(Plane1{:})
```

Comment: Yes, in that case you can use a loop with the names in a cell array - ` {'Plane1','Plan2','Plane3','Plane4'}`

Comment: Or `unique(Line(:,2))` in general. But you probably need the ugly `eval` to set the variable names. Perhaps you would rather want to save to a struct with the planes as fieldnames.

Comment: Well I tried `unique` and tried to use the third O/P arg, which gave sort of weird results, but yes that could be looked into.

Comment: ohh this appeared while I was posting... I think structure would be the way to go, and why did I not think of `vertcat`